# Static content compression is not working IIS 10 AKAMAI CDN

Tags: asp.net, iis, compression, iis-10, akamai

I am facing challenges with static content compression on IIS 10.0. We are facing this challenge when we leverage AKAMAI CDN service. Compression is working fine if we try to connect to the host directly. We have already enabled static content compression in the IIS panel. We have also set **noCompressionForHttp10 and noCompressionForProxies** settings on IIS to False. but still we are getting uncompressed content. Please help if there is any other setting that need to be fix.

Comment: What Akamai product are you trying to use? There are settings that allow for compression of objects.

Comment: Akamai cdn services

Answer (score 0):

Static compression typically is applicable to the files that do not typically change, such as `HTML`(*.html, *.htm),text file(*.txt). the size of these files can be reduced through compress, which reduces download times for client requests and reduces bandwidth on the server.
There is an attribute to control whether a static file is compressed only if it is hit a certain number of times within a time period. Please consider disabling the `StaticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency`.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/
https://weblogs.asp.net/anilkasalanati/enabling-http-caching-and-compression-in-iis-7-for-asp-net-websites

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks but this setting did not work for me.. Please note that I am getting CSS and JS files in compressed format but not HTML files. Is there any specific setting in IIS that I need to enable/disable.

Comment: I don't know any other settings affecting this issue. please try to start a new session to check after applying the settings. Please check to see whether the response HTTP header contains `Content-Encoding:gzip`.

Comment: I did but this header was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Akamai delivers content compressed or uncompressed based on the product you're using (Ion Premier, Adaptive Media Delivery, Dynamic Site Accelerator, etc.) and the behaviors you've enabled within that product.

In general, the Akamai product needs a configuration rule similar to this:
[image: Akamai Property Manager displaying the default "Compressible Objects" rule in Ion Premier]

Notice there's an IF clause that matches against the Content-Type header. If a piece of content matches that Content-Type, then it will be compressed by Akamai and delivered to the end user with GZIP compression. Additionally, you can have the Edge server deliver it uncompressed ("Never") or to simply follow what your IIS server is sending ("Same as origin behavior").

Additional compression options and more complex rule matching are available in Property Manager. This image is just the default "Compressible Objects" rule as part of the Ion Premier product.

Comment: Thanks but akamai is already delivering compressed content to the end users. issue is with the origin server. Origin server is delivering uncompressed content to the akamai server which is leading to more bandwidth consumption. Seems like there is something missing on the origin server (IIS). Lastly, we are using DSA product of AKAMAI.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood where you were seeing the content uncompressed.